# Attempting canary deployment of API endpoint with API-M, but backend service url is overridden in backend section

Tags: azure-api-management

I have set up my API-M endpoint against the current production endpoint, and this works fine. I now want to point a small percentage of visitors to a new (and hopefully improved) endpoint, but if it fails I want API-M to retry the request against the current endpoint.

I have set up a policy as such,configured with a 100% chance of hitting the canary while I get this to work. The inbound part was taken from the sample at https://github.com/Azure/api-management-samples/blob/914f1032583dd9e1a1ca8ba01eaba247290fa134/policies/Route%20percentage%20of%20traffic%20to%20canary.policy.xml:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="canaryPercentage" value="@(100)" />
        <set-variable name="canaryBackendServiceUrl" value="https://new-base-uri" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(new Random().Next(100) < context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<int>("canaryPercentage"))">
                <set-backend-service base-url="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("canaryBackendServiceUrl"))" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <retry condition="@(context.Response != null && context.Response.StatusCode >= 500)" count="10" interval="10" max-interval="100" delta="10" first-fast-retry="true">
            <set-backend-service base-url="https://old-base-uri" />
            <forward-request timeout="10" />
        </retry>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

The inbound part works, according to the trace. This is the very last log message from the "Inbound" section:

```
set-backend-service (0.038 ms)
{
    "message": "Backend service URL was changed.",
    "oldBackendServiceUrl": "https://old-base-uri/",
    "newBackendServiceUrl": "https://new-base-uri",
    "request": {
        "url": "https://new-base-uri/endpoint"
    }
}
```

But the very next day, it throws it away (sorry for whamming it up this morning - this is the very first statement in the "Backend" section):

```
set-backend-service (0.016 ms)
{
    "message": "Backend service URL was changed.",
    "oldBackendServiceUrl": "https://new-base-uri",
    "newBackendServiceUrl": "https://old-base-uri/",
    "request": {
        "url": "https://old-base-uri/endpoint"
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why this happens, as there's no reference to  in the backend element of the policy.

What I would like to happen, is that the request should first be forwarded to the canary (new) endpoint, and if that fails with a server side error (>=500), the the request is retried against the production endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve this myself. I must admit that the API-M syntax is a bit confusing, but the trick was to double-check the condition, both in the retry element and in the choose element. Also note the set-body element - it is needed, along with setting the incoming body as a variable. Without it, no body will be posted with the retry request, and you will end up with this error:

```
forward-request (1.326 ms)
{
"messages": [
    "Content length mismatch",
    "Content length mismatch"
    ]
}
```

The variable is set in the inbound element:

```
<set-variable name="body" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true))" />
```

The complete backend element which makes this work:

```
 <backend>
        <retry condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 400)" count="1" interval="0" first-fast-retry="true">
            <choose>
                <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 400)">
                    <set-backend-service base-url="https://production-uri" />
                </when>
            </choose>
            <set-body>@((string)context.Variables["body"])</set-body>
            <forward-request />
        </retry>
    </backend>
```